# C# Workflow code activity result

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Hello I am very new worklows. I am attempting to build a proof of concept workflow that will process all files in a specified directory. I have added a foreach loop and then a codeactivity (ValidateXml), the code activity validates the xml and returns bool, it inherits the CodeActivity class.

Now i you take a look at the picture, I would like to use the result of the codeactivity in the WriteLine activity.

Please help me in how to do that.

Thank you![image]

Comment: I provided an answer first. :(

Comment: @HMChan Hello, I upvoted your post, and true, you provided the answer first. However, the one I marked as correct was easier for a noob to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy what you wanto to do. See in the screenshot below:

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1):

Add a `bool` variable, say `bValid` in Sequence Activity. In the properties dialog of `ValidateXml`, assign Result to the `bValid`. `bValid` will contain the return value of `ValidateXml` activity.